# Tools to measure the performance Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, testing

I am choosing web server for my Rails application and looking for applications to measure performance of Rails application.

Can you recomend me good software for this aim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what kind of performance? you could try [newrelic](http://newrelic.com)

Comment: I am looking for a tool which automatically generate http-request for my applications and measure the time of response, count of requests in sec and so on.

Comment: Maybe Apache benchmark: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Comment: newrelic can do that and it even shows you the problems and which line of code slows down your app